# como puedo descargar archivos mediante php?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, funciones

Hola comunidad espero puedan ayudarme con este código que lo necesito mucho...

quiero descargar archivos del servidor mediante php para no mostrar la ruta como se hace en html.
en la página donde quiero descargar tengo un boton que llama a una funcion js, la cual por ajax envio la ruta a otro archivo php, en el cual tengo mi función para descargar pero la verdad no hace nada

```
//el botón que llama al js
 <div class="btn btn-success btn-sm ml-3" onclick="funcion_dw('<?php echo $dir; ?>')">descarga</div>

//aca la función js que contiene el ajax
function funcion_dw(ruta) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "descarga.php",
            data: "ruta=" + ruta,
            success: function(r) {
            }
        });
    }

//acá la pagina descarga.php quien realizaría la función de descargar el archivo, pero no hace nada
$ruta = $_POST['ruta'];
$archivo = basename($ruta);

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$archivo\"");
readfile($ruta);
```

---

estoy haciendo esto pero no funciona, pensaba que pasando los archivos del directorio específico a un arreglo podría funcionar,@Triby podrias revisar en que estoy fallando? me base en tu respuesta para recorrer e insertar los archivos en un array

```
$src =  $_POST['ruta'];
$anexo_ruta="aca/el/origen/de/la/ruta";

        function dirToArray($dir)
        {
            $listDir = array();
            if ($handler = opendir($dir)) {
                while (($file = readdir($handler)) !== FALSE) {
                    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." ) {
                        if (is_file($dir . "/" . $file)) {
                            $listDir[$file] = $dir . $file;
                        }
                    }
                }
                closedir($handler);
            }
            return $listDir;
        }
$ruta_completa=$anexo_ruta.$src;
$archivos = dirToArray($ruta_completa);
        

$archivo = basename($src);        
$ruta = $archivos[$archivo];
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$archivo\"");
readfile($ruta);
```

Comment: Saludos. La `ruta` que envias debe ser realmente **la ruta junto con el nombre del archivo y extensión** ; conforme a tu esquema debes recibir la *ruta específica* o *ruta relativa*. Creo te falta algunas consideraciones adicionales; mira en https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.readfile.php espero  te sirva; tambien da vistazo a https://www.phptpoint.com/how-to-download-file-in-php/#:~:text=PHP%20Download%20File,-%C2%AB%20Previous%20Next%20%C2%BB&text=php%20%24f%3D%22resume.,%3A%20attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22.

Comment: en la variable ruta, envío completa la ruta del archivo incluyendo la extensión... revise los link que recomendaste, en donde copie tal cual los ejemplos pero aun sin tener nada concreto :/

Answer (score 1):

No se puede descargar un archivo por AJAX porque, por motivos de seguridad, Javascript no puede acceder directamente al diálogo de descarga y, además, no tiene sentido, es suficiente con que el enlace te envíe directamente al script que realizará la descarga.

Si aún quieres hacerlo con una función javascript, armas la URL y rediriges con `window.location.href`:

```
//el botón que llama al js
 <div class="btn btn-success btn-sm ml-3" onclick="funcion_dw('<?php echo $dir; ?>')">descarga</div>

function funcion_dw(ruta) {
    window.location.href = 'descarga.php?ruta=' + ruta;
}
```

El navegador iniciará la descarga, quedándose en la misma página y el problema aquí no es solo que la ruta del archivo es visible, sino que no haces validaciones; desde el inspector se puede copiar o modificar HTML y javascript para descargar cualquier cosa, por ejemplo:

Un usuario malintencionado copia los datos y teclea en el navegador `descarga.php?ruta=descarga.php`... ¡Sí, va a descargar el código fuente del script de descarga! Y, con un poco de paciencia, puede obtener todo tu sitio.

### ¿Qué hacer?

Por lo general, se tiene un catálogo de archivos disponibles, cada uno con una ID específica que es lo que se usa para generar el enlace. Si se trata de pocos archivos y no van a estar cambiando, basta con ponerlos en un arreglo:

```
$archivos = [
  'id-archivo1' => ['Título de archivo 1', 'ruta/nombre-archivo.ext'],
  'id-archivo2' => ['Título de archivo 2', 'ruta/nombre-archivo.ext'],
  'id-archivoX' => ['Título de archivo X', 'ruta/nombre-archivo.ext'],
];
```

Si tienes muchos archivos o pueden cambiar, lo mejor sería usar una tabla en la base de datos.

El código HTML se simplifica:

```
<a href="descarga.php?archivo=id-archivoX">Título del archivo X</a>
```

En PHP, suponiendo que tienes los archivos en un arreglo:

```
// Asegurar que hay variable en URL
$idArchivo = (isset($_GET['archivo'])) ? $_GET['archivo'] : '';
// Validar que existe el archivo
if(!isset($archivos[$idArchivo]) || !file_exists($archivos[$idArchivo][1])) {
    die('Acceso no permitido');
}
$ruta = $archivos[$idArchivo][1];
$archivo = basename($ruta);

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$archivo\"");
readfile($ruta);
```

Ahora ya no muestras la ruta real del archivo y manejas seguridad ante ataques básicos, recuerda que no hay sistema 100% seguro.

Comment: funcionaria si, le envio la ruta, abro la ruta del directorio y lo recorro, insertando todos los archivos en un array, luego descargo de ese nuevo array??... en la ruta que l envio por ajax no seria la ruta completa, sino que solo parte de ella, y en la pagina descarga completo el total de ruta para recorrer el directorio completo

Comment: ¿Quieres que todos los archivos en una carpeta se puedan descargar?

Comment: si, la idea es que se descargue todos los archivos disponible por cada directorio

Comment: @OscarSantander: ¿Cuántos directorios planeas tener para descarga y qué tipo(s) de archivos se van a poder descargar?

Comment: son multiples directorios, se crea una carpeta padre por año, dentro de esta van minimo 12 carpetas, las cuales a su vez tienen multiples directorios hijos, y asi sucesivamente. en estos directorios se pueden almacenar todo tipo de archivos, desde los mas basicos como .doc, .xlsx, .ppt, .jpg y tambien algunas veces algunos archivos .exe que estaran contenidos dentro de algun .rar

Comment: Edita la pregunta y pon el código que usas para listar los archivos a descargar. Es la mejor forma de proponerte una respuesta útil.